# Alguien que me puedan explicar cual es la diferencia entre estos 2 códigos

Tags: html, html5

estoy aprendiendo html y estoy en la parte de form, la cosa es que tuve un problema con un código, ya que el primero código al intentar enviarlo no pasa nada, pero el segundo si se manda a otra pagina, me podrían explicar porque no funciona el primer código, pero el segundo si.
Al menos yo no veo ninguna diferencia, pero me gustaría que ustedes me digan cual si es que la hay, o el porque el primero no funciona pero el segundo si.

1.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pagina nashe</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="fotos nashe/enrabiao.ico">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/formulario" method="GET"> 
        <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" />
        <br>
        <label for="apellido">Apellido</label>
        <input type="text" id="apellido" name="apellido" placeholder="Apellido">
        <br>
        <label for="Comentario">Comentario</form></label>
        <textarea cols="50" rows="10" id="comentario" name="comentario" placeholder="Igrese un comentario">este es un valor por defecto</textarea>
        <br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <a href="#codigo">Click Aquí</a> para ir a la siguiente noticia
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        
    </p>
    <h2 id="codigo">
        Reyna es gooood
    </h2>
    <center>
    <img src="fotos nashe/nashe.jfif" alt="Nashe" title="Nasheeee">
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

2. 

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Mi pagina web</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/formulario" method="GET">
        <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
        <br>
        <label for="apellido">Apeliido</label>
        <input type="text" id="apellido" name="apellido" placeholder="Apellido">
        <br>
        <label for="comentario">Comentario</label>
        <textarea cols="50" rows="10"  type="text" id="comentario" name="comentario" placeholder="Ingrese un comentario"> </textarea>
        <br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <h1>Esta es mi primera pagina web donde contaré sobre mi vida</h1>
    <h2>Esto se tratara sobre historias de mi vida</h2>
    <p>En esta biografia hablaré de muchas facetas de mi vida donde pasaré por muchos momentos buenos y malos</p>
    <hr>
    <h2>Mi infancia</h2>
    <p>Todo empezó cuando recién tenia 5 años, <span style="color:blue">era un niño feliz y divertido,</span> que se la pasaba <br>
         divirtiendose con sus jugetes</p>
    <!-- Este comentario hablaré como hice mi codigo, lo hice facilmente con unos videos de youtube aprendiendo autonomamente en mi habitación-->
    <a target="_blanck" href="https://www.google.com">Ir a mi instagram</a> <br>
    <img src="Foticos/enrabiao.jpg"  width="300" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: En el primer código no están cerrando todas las etiquetas html, ¿lo habías dejado así? Vamos falta el </body> y el </html> (al menos)

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en que en el primer formulario se te ha colado una etiqueta de cierre de `</form>` antes de que aparezca el `<input type="submit">`. Luego ese submit, al no estar dentro de ningún formulario, no haría nada.

```html
<form action="/formulario" method="GET"> 
  <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
  <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" />
  <br>
  <label for="apellido">Apellido</label>
  <input type="text" id="apellido" name="apellido" placeholder="Apellido">
  <br>
  <label for="Comentario">Comentario<!-- sobra --></form><!-- sobra --></label>
  <textarea cols="50" rows="10" id="comentario" name="comentario" placeholder="Igrese un comentario">este es un valor por defecto</textarea>
  <br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: De verdad muchas gracias<3